# Astuce pour choisir entre de et des

Tags: grammaire

Je comprends les différences de grammaire (plus ou moins) entre de et des, mais j'arrive pas à savoir laquelle il faut utiliser dans mes phrases. Y-a-t-il une astuce pour se décider, un grammar trick où une question a se poser peut être ?

Je parle des cas comme : « sortie de voitures » où on utilise la préposition *de* au lieu de *des*

Je suppose qu'il s'agit de la même chose pour l'expression « compagnie de mitrailleuse » dans le transcrit de [cette émission](https://savoirs.rfi.fr/en/apprendre-enseigner/histoire/14-18-les-debuts-du-jazz-en-france/1)

Ici si on remplaçait de avec des je sens qu'on aurait changé le sens de mot, mais je ne suis pas sûr dans quelle sens.